# How to properly serialize a sortable SQLCLR User-Defined Type?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sorting, sqlclr

I am building a custom User-Defined Type in C# for use with SQL CLR. [See this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131120.aspx).

The underlying data can be represented in 4 bytes using a regular signed 32-bit integer.  Here is the implementation:

```cs
[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedType(Format.UserDefined, IsByteOrdered = true,
                    IsFixedLength = true, MaxByteSize = 4)]
public struct MyUDT : INullable, IBinarySerialize
{
    private int _value;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }

    public MyUDT(int value)
        : this()
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    [SqlMethod(OnNullCall = false)]
    public static MyUDT Parse(SqlString s)
    {
        int i = int.Parse(s.Value);
        return new MyUDT(i);
    }

    public bool IsNull { get; private set; }
    public static MyUDT Null
    {
        get { return new MyUDT { IsNull = true }; }
    }

    public void Read(BinaryReader r)
    {
        var bytes = r.ReadBytes(4);

        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(bytes);

        int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
        _value = i ^ unchecked((int) 0x80000000);
    }

    public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
    {
        int i = _value ^ unchecked((int) 0x80000000);
        var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);

        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(bytes);

        w.Write(bytes);
    }
}
```

Of course, I will add other methods that will make this more useful, but this is the minimum that will compile and publish.

I need to make sure that when this type is used for comparisons, such as when it is a column in a table, that it is sorted correctly.  There will be both positive and negative values.

As you can see, I had to reverse the byte ordering, because the endianness is backwards.  I also had to adjust the bytes so that zero is represented as `0x80000000`, and -1 becomes `0x7FFFFFFF`.  Otherwise the values don't get sorted properly.

However, this is *not* how SQL Server integers normally work.  For example:

```sql
SELECT convert(varbinary, -16)  -- 0xFFFFFFF0
SELECT convert(varbinary, 16)   -- 0x00000010
```

Yet these sort just fine!  So I can only conclude that there are other sorting types than just raw order of bytes.  But I can't find any way to control that in my UDT.  Is it possible?

All of the examples I've found show something like this:

```cs
public void Read(BinaryReader r)
{
    _value = r.ReadInt32();
}

public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
{
    w.Write(_value);
}
```

But that writes in a completely different format. It's like SQL Server's format, but the endianness is reversed  (1 is `0x01000000` and -16 is `0xF0FFFFFF`).  So things get sorted completely wrong.  So are the examples wrong? Is there a bug somewhere?

I have also considered using `Format.Native` and omitting the custom serialization.  That sort of works, but I end up with 5 byte values, where zero looks like `0x8000000000` and -1 looks like `0x7FFFFFFF00`.  It is automatically converting just like I did, but it stores an extra byte for the `IsNull` boolean field.  It won't accept having that marked as `[NonSerialized]`, and it won't let me remove that.  Nullability is a requirement, so it has to be there.

Surely there is a simpler way than having to do bit manipulation?

Another concern is that my type isn't directly convertible to an `int` within SQL.  Although, I'm not sure if I need that or not.

See also, a [related (but different) question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/47115/23221) on DBA.SE.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to implement IComparable and set IsByteOrdered to false.  This would eliminate the need to play games by converting zero to `0x80000000` and -1 to `07FFFFFFF`.

I'll finish off by saying, I'm not even a beginner at this stuff.  Never done it myself, but I glanced over the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131082.aspx

Comment: That would be quite nice, but looking at the docs you linked, in the first "Note" box, it says that `IComparable` is not used by the server.  It's only there for client-side stuff.  I'm mostly interested in the sorting being correct when querying a table that has this UDT in a column.

Comment: Ah, you are correct.  Sorry that didn't help.  You might try using Format.Native, that might force it to serialize the signed ints so that they are sortable (kind of how you are doing it yourself).

Comment: As for it storing the NULL byte, if your type truly can't ever be NULL, you might try creating the IsNull and Null properties so that they don't reference anything, and only have gets with no sets.